# What does "clean cut whimsy" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Could you please explain me what does "clean cut whimsy" mean? I truly have no idea. I'm trying to understand this figure of speech word by word, but it doesn't work.

> The Cosby Show was wildly popular for a reason: it executed the family
>   sitcom formula better than any other program. The stories were
>   moralizing but plausible, the laughs were genuine, and the cast was
>   solid from top to bottom. Though he’s become less universally beloved
>   in his later years, Bill Cosby is undeniably one of the most talented
>   comedians ever to grace the American stage, and he carried the show
>   that bore his name with his finely honed brand of **clean cut whimsy**.
>
> [Source](https://deadhomersociety.com/zombiesimpsons/zs2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, word by word does not work here. You want to consider "clean-cut":

> [clean-cut](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/clean-cut)
>   adjective
>   A clean-cut man is tidy in appearance and behaves well:
>   • Julie's fiancé is a nice clean-cut young man.
>   (Cambridge Dictionary)

The hyphen is not mandatory, but it is often written that way. I assume you can understand "whimsy".

This word fits well as Cosby did dress tidily in the show, and his nature and humor were wholesome.

Comment: I’d be a little stronger here: the hyphen is close to mandatory. 

Comment: The answer is wrong. You have to have a hyphen.

Comment: @Fattie - That's more a matter of style than correctness. As two-word phrases become stock phrases, hyphens often get dropped.

Comment: The sentence makes sense without the hyphen, even if you want to be prescriptive about "clean-cut". It means that the whimsical sections of Cosby's performance were seamlessly edited (i.e. cut).

Comment: @alephzero It might be grammatical that way, but it hardly makes sense in context. Would the quality of editing really have that much impact on whether a comedian is "beloved"?

Comment: @Em. The question was "What does “clean cut whimsy” mean?" You assume the questioner understands "whimsy" and you explain that "Crosby did dress tidily" but you didn't explain why the *whimsy* was described as clean-cut. Nonetheless your answer was accepted. If the questioner *meant* to ask "What does 'clean cut' mean?" your answer might be acceptable. But would you explain what "clean cut WHIMSY" means?

Comment: @OldBrixtonian I may not have been as explicit as you were, but I feel like I addressed that in "his nature and humor were wholesome", as that's what "whimsy" roughly refers to.

Comment: @Em. I guess you're right. I understood the question to be about the transferred epithet,